# Use Schema names in NHibernate Query - Version 1.2.0

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'n using NHibernate 1.2.0 and cannot migrate to a newer version. 
1.2.0 does not allow me to do Restrictions so that I can replace empty strings with nothing.

I am trying to do the following using CreateQuery

```
SELECT Col1, COl2 FROM [Employee].[MyTable] WHERE REPLACE(Col1, " ", "") = 'IWANTTHIS'
```

Somehow NHibernate does not like [Employee].[MyTable] 
Is there any other way I can do this or fix what I am doing? I have not idea! Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateQuery` is for performing HQL queries - which are written as queries of objects, not DB tables.

From the looks of your example you want to do an SQL query, so `CreateSQLQuery` would be the one to use.

However, in my opinoin you should seriously think about rewriting this using ICriteria or HQL.  Is there wny reason shy you have to specify the low level SQL?

Comment: No there is not reason for using low level sql as long as I can do the job. Would ICriteria support the replace function to get rid of the empty spaces? Please be mindful I am using 1.2 version of Hibernate. There is no way we can migrate to 2.--- without spending extraordinary amounts of time and money